# Referencing locations within a text box

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, text

I have a node I've drawn in tikz, like this:

```
\node[below, text width=5cm] (SomeName) at (0,0) {
    \begin{itemize}
        \item line 1
        \item line 2
        \item line 3
        \item line 4
        \item line 5
    \end{itemize}
}
```

I would like to draw an arrow from line 2 to the side to another node I've constructed.
I would also like to be able to place a bracket around line 4 and 5 to then draw a different arrow to yet another node.

The items are not strictly one line items, so I would like to be able to place some reference within the text (if possible) to be able to construct my lines rather than positioning the line some fraction of the way down the box constructed by my node.

For a complete code spinet that will provide the image of what I'm looking for:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[below, text width=5cm] (SomeName) at (0,0) {
    \begin{itemize}
        \item line 1
        \item line 2
        \item line 3
        \item line 4
        \item line 5
    \end{itemize}
};
\node[below, text width=2cm] (Other) at (-5,0) {
    Some text will go here.
};
\node[below, text width=2cm] (Another) at (-5,-4) {
    Some text will go here.
};
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=7pt,mirror}](-2,-2) -- (-2,-3) node[midway,left] (A) {};% A node must have a (possibly empty) label text.

\draw[-stealth] (-2,-1.5) -- (Other.east);
\draw[-stealth] (A.west) -- (Another.east);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have the brackets and arrows coming from the itemized list be node references rather than trouble shooting to get them in approximately the right location.

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal document rather than a mere fragment of pseudo-code, which is not terribly useful to anybody who wants to understand your question, reproduce the problem and see whether they might be able to help. (Solving problems is fun. Setting them up is boring.) You can probably use **tikzmark**'s `subnode`s. The documentation is good. You just load as a library and are good to go. `subnode`s are especially easy to reference, so you should find it straightforward. I'd demonstrate if there was an example but don't feel like starting from scratch now. (Soembody else may.)

Comment: @Jeremie, you could read the section 17.13.1 in the [manual](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf). Anyway, I think this question already has an answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91675/tikz-node-at-item-to-use-in-overlay)

Comment: It should be noted that calling tikz or tikzmark inside a node can occasionally cause problems.  However, one can overcome this by putting the text into \savebox then putting \usebox into the node.

Comment: @JohnKormylo **tikzmark** provides `\subnode` specifically for use inside nodes in TikZ pictures. That's the whole point of the command.

Answer (score 3):

This solution uses **tikzmark** and involves turning the `itemize` environment into an `enumerate` using the `label` option of **enumitem**. The list looks just the same, but the item number is used to turn the bullets into sub-nodes which can be referenced later in the picture.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt, multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{calc,enumitem}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.text,tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node[below, text width=5cm] (SomeName) at (0,0) {%
    \begin{enumerate}[label={\subnode{it\arabic*}{\textbullet}}]
      \item line 1
      \item line 2
      \item line 3
      \item line 4
      \item line 5
    \end{enumerate}%
  };
  \node[below, text width=2cm] (Other) at (-5,0) {Some text will go here.};
  \node[below, text width=2cm] (Another) at (-5,-4) {Some text will go here.};
  \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=7pt,mirror}] (it3.north west) -- (it4.south west) node[midway,left] (A) {};
  \draw[-Stealth] (it2) -- (Other.east);
  \draw[-Stealth] ([xshift=-2.5pt]A.west) -- (Another.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: marked pseudo-itemised list]

Comment: thanks for taking a look. I like how your solution looks, but for some reason when I run this code the nodes are not lining up the same (rather than being right on the bullets, they are instead half way into the node containing the enumerated list). This is resulting in the arrows and bracket being placed on top of the text. It would seem that if the node's top corner were the coordinate I'm defining (rather than the center of the top), then this solution would work perfectly. That seems like a work around to me rather than a solution.

Comment: @Jeremie Did you compile twice? Are you externalising TikZ pictures? I don't really understand what you mean seems like a workaround.

Comment: I did compile twice. I'm currently not doing any externalizing. As for the work around, I was just thinking about if I shifted something to adjust for the fact that the nodes did not line up where expected (as they are at the center of the box rather than near the side of the box where the dots are).

Comment: Do you get the wrong output if you compile exactly the code I posted as a new document? If so, I'm not sure what might be wrong. I used `pdflatex` and I'm using more-or-less  current TeX Live 2015. If the minimal example works, but it does not work in your real document, you'd need to make a minimal example which reproduces the problem and maybe ask a new question about it. (I think that would be clearer than editing it into this one.)

Comment: I copied and pasted the document you have here, and that is where I'm seeing the shifted arrow and bracket from what I expect (and your result). It is in the right spot vertically, just not horizontally.

Comment: @Jeremie Then I can only think that it is a difference in versions, assuming you are using `pdflatex` etc. Is your TeX distribution up to date?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I used `remember picture` option for `tikzpicture`s to allow the connection between `node`s defined in different `tikzpicture`s (cf. $17.13.1 in the [manual](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf)).
I used `minipage` to arrange the three block, but other solutions are possible.
To overcome a difficulty in the spacing around the `node` containing the `$bullet$` I referred to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27893/how-to-do-something-like-inner-sep-west-specify-inner-sep-on-just-only-one).

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}



\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{3cm}
\begin{minipage}{3cm}
\tikz[remember picture]\node (n1) {Some text will go here};
\end{minipage}
\\[1cm]
\begin{minipage}{3cm}
\tikz[remember picture]\node (n2) {Some text will go here};
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{10mm}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item line 1

\item[{\tikz[remember picture]\node[inner xsep=5pt,inner ysep=0] (t2) {$\bullet\hspace{-5pt}$};}] line 2

\item[{\tikz[remember picture]\node[inner sep=0] (t3) {$\bullet$};}] line 3

\item[{\tikz[remember picture]\node[inner sep=0] (t4) {$\bullet$};}] line 4

\item line 5

\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}


\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\path[->] (n1.east) edge [out=0 , in=180] (t2.west);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt},thick] (t4.south west) -- node[left,anchor=east,inner xsep=5pt] (t34) {} (t3.north west);
\path[->] (n2.east) edge [out=0 , in=180] (t34.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```